# Can I ask about the design model of an open source project in software engineering?

Tags: support

I found a repo of an open source project on github (if you like to know, it is https://github.com/openstack/python-openstacksdk ).

I want to contribute to it, but I don't know the project's design model.

So, can I ask about the design model of this project on softwareengineering.stackexchange?

---

**EDIT**

Some time ago, I asked this question on SO meta:https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343689/can-i-ask-a-question-about-the-project-design-idea

They said this type question should be asked on Software Engineering.

Comment: see [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266909/839601)

Comment: @gnat: I think this question is clearly answerable without viewing the external link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On stackoverflow, you asked *"can I ask a question about a project's design idea"*, which gives the impression you want us to make a review of a design model you have created by yourself, or seen somewhere. So one answerer told you - correctly - to ask here on Softwarengineering, because design reviews are on-topic here.

However, here in this meta question, you clarified you are not going to present a design model, and you do not ask for review. Instead, you want to ask how to find information about (or maybe reverse engineer) the design model of an  existing open source project with a large code base. That looks like a different question to me, and none which is on-topic here, as @MetaFight has already explained.

So please don't blame us for giving you a different answer here on Meta than the audience on SO, since you asked a different question there.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that doesn't sound like a good question for our site.

We don't have that information.  Only the repo maintainer would have that and it's not likely you'll find them here.

Have you tried looking through their README, or issue tracker, or maybe asking on gitter if they use that?

Their documentation has a section on how to contribute.

https://developer.openstack.org/sdks/python/openstacksdk/contributors/index.html

Comment: See my Edit, friend.

Comment: Regarding your update:  Unfortunately, the person who referred you here did it mistakenly.  To be fair to them, they did suggest you read our help center before posting.  To be fair to you, you did ask on Meta instead of just posting.  So all in all, no harm done and the system works :)  Out of curiosity, though.  Have you looked at the "contributing" link in my answer?

Comment: Before ask this quest,  I have read it several months ago. I did not find the design model, also ask the other users.